# PHP - IMAP - Is it possible to get receivers email address from a sent email?

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm trying to retrieve the receivers email address from an email sent from my email client. I use PHP and IMAP to get the job done, but i'm stuck at the moment since i can't get the receivers email address from the email. It only seems possible to get the name of the receiver.

Does anyone know if this can be done and how to do it?

Comment: `Email sent from my client` ? If you sent the email, how you do not know the email address? How do you send the email without knowing? Or are you trying to read the "sent emails" from the email account, and get the email address there?

Comment: And are you using the PHP imap library? please add clear information to your question if you want others to post clear answers.

Comment: I'm using PHP imap library. I want to access "sent emails" directly from my PHP script. I can find "fromaddress" and "toaddress" when i search my inbox, but not when i search in sent emails.

Comment: From which email provider are you trying to get this? Gmail or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get the receiver's email address from the message header information. You need to call the `imap_headerinfo()` function for each message.

```
imap_headerinfo($connection, $msg);
```

This would return an object with all the headers in it like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    .
    .
    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [mailbox] => testemail
                    [host] => gmail.com
                )
        )
)
```

You can concatenate the `mailbox` and `host` of the `to` property to get the email of the receiver. Here's an example:

```
$connection = imap_open($host, $uname, $pwd) or die(imap_last_error());
$messages = imap_search($connection, 'ALL');

foreach($messages as $msg) {
    $header = imap_headerinfo($connection, $msg);

    foreach($header->to as $receiver){
        echo $receiver->mailbox.'@'.$receiver->host.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what i was looking for.